# How did Kang's variants banish Kang to the Quantum Realm?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania

In the 2023 movie, *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, it's revealed that Kang's variants have banished Kang to the Quantum Realm.

But how did they know about the Realm first of all? And how did they exile him there? Did they have Pym particles? Did they have a machine like what the protagonists had in *Ant-Man and the Wasp*?

Comment: The whole plot of the movie is about Kang trying to repair his ship so he can escape. The trapped him there by tampering with the ship.

Comment: He got there between 1980s and 2018. But how? First of all, you should have a technology to sub-atomize yourself.

Comment: The Kangs are from the 31st century. Their technology is a lot more advanced than present day MCU. Also "time works differently in the quantum realm".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Remembering the Third Doctor here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot So did the Kangs travel in time or the protagonists?